# pre-conditions and database interaction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, specflow

let me ask you something, if a have scenario like this:

```
Scenario: Listing the questions for a user that has answered questions 
        Given I am a logged user called "vintem" 
         And I have the following projects 
                | Project   | 
                | Project 1 | 
                | Project 2 | 
        When I visit the projects page 
        Then I should see 
        | Project   | 
        | Project 1 | 
        | Project 2 |
```

What would you generally do in this case to create the projects the 
must be seen in the projects page? Suppose I am using a Repository 
pattern would call the repository itself to create the projects?
Or simulate the creation of the projects using Watin? 
In the case of calling the repository directly, my connection to 
database would have to be same as the one in the web project right? I 
can't have a test db and a dev db in that case. 
Thanks

Comment: Is this for the purposes of unit testing?

Comment: I am trying to use it as BDD style. As a result I'd like that to be an acceptance test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Given is there to set the context. It does not *have* to use the same constructs as the When or the then. You could if you wished just insert the projects in to the DB with straight SQL, It doesn't matter. What I wouldn't do is user Watin to set up the projects. This will make your tests more brittle as changes to the UI will effect your test. They will also run slower

You say you are using the repository pattern. As indicated I'd use that along with sqllite for the back-end.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I am doing now.